# Are tag synonyms even benefitting StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Why do we have tag synonyms? Do they really help? If I search for imaginary "Tag1", would its imaginary synonym "Tag2" also be searched?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are useful. Tag synonyms are for tags that get created a lot, when they're a dupe of another tag.

For example, for every release of Ubuntu we synonymize it's code name:

Saucy -> 13.10

Raring -> 13.04

We do this because we don't need two tags for the same thing floating around.

And, yes it will provide the results when searching:

[image]