# I need to improve my questions

Tags: discussion, up-votes

I noticed that many of my questions are not getting up-votes. How can I improve my questions? The one the seems the most odd to me is ([Are tag synonyms even benefitting StackExchange?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6897/are-tag-synonyms-even-benefitting-stackexchange)). It seems odd because answer received a few upvotes, but the question received none. It seems odd that a good answer can exist for a poor question. What can I do to receive more upvotes?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read through the [/help](http://askubuntu.com/help) center. Particularly concerning [meta](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-meta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, I guess it is in the beginning normal not to be up-voted too often, cause one is somehow a "greenhorn" with less than 100 or less than 200 points in reputation. - Ma, but you can enfluence being up-voted a bit, by up-voting yourself others contributions. In the end it is a matter of each others giving and taking ( not praying here for "christianity-over-all-manhood" ! ). It is matter of patience too until you have the right grasp and the right grip for dealing with Linux/Unix - topics. So don't worry too much about that ! Soon it is coming earlier or later - the right grasp and the right grip, by writing, editing and reading new impacts.

Answer (score 5):

Meta is for discussing things about the main site.

Unless you're posting something that is a huge problem that people care about this is just the day-to-day boring admin side of the site. I can't imagine being passionate about tag-synonyms. :) I personally don't usually vote often here, to me it's all about the main site.